# how to return the JSON of a javascript object in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF app with a WebBrowser control

I need to get the JSON string of a javascript object, something like this:

```
var json = this.WebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "JSON.stringify(window.mainThing)" });
```

I am executing this code on WebBrowser's LoadCompleted event

this throws an exception

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code

```
  HResult=-2147352319
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101
  Source=WindowsBase
  ErrorCode=-2147352319
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.Interop.HRESULT.ThrowIfFailed(String message)
       at System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser.InvokeScript(String scriptName, Object[] args)
```

Here's the Javascript in the page:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>    window.mainThing = { x : 1 };
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

WPF [WebBrowser.InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452443.aspx) has a different method signature from WinForms [HtmlDocument.InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1a88bz.aspx). Try this:

```
var json = this.WebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "JSON.stringify(window.mainThing)");
```

Comment: nope, the problem is in the IE Compatibility view. The JSON is not available in older versions of IE I think. Check this: http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem is in the IE Compatibility View
I need to setup some registry keys

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"vshost.exe"=dword:00002328
"vshost32.exe"=dword:00002328
"MyAppName.exe"=dword:00002328
"MyAppName.vshost.exe"=dword:00002328

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"vshost.exe"=dword:00002328
"vshost32.exe"=dword:00002328
"MyAppName.exe"=dword:00002328
"MyAppName.vshost.exe"=dword:00002328

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"vshost.exe"=dword:00002328
"vshost32.exe"=dword:00002328
"MyAppName.exe"=dword:00002328
"MyAppName.vshost.exe"=dword:00002328
```